# How to remove the clicked word in GridView using android studio?

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I want to remove the clicked word from Gridview but I don't know how?
for example if i want to remove for example "house"  I should click it and it will be removed.
I tried to use onclick but I got an error.

```
mainActivity:
package com.example.hi.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gv;
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    names.add("hi");
    names.add("go");
    names.add("went");
    names.add("house");
    names.add("home");
    names.add("blind");
    names.add("ears");
    names.add("hear");


    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_id);

    //adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.hi.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:id="@+id/gridview_id" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please search on stackoverflow before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set an OnItemClickListener, then inside the block add the code to remove an item

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

           names.remove(position);              
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: great, please accept the answer by clicking the "✓" sign if you find it helpful.